# Find specific value with PHP SQL in database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, while-loop

I have a Mysql table called IP which holds some rows in a column called IP (also), looks like this:

```
82.161.217.164
82.161.217.164
82.161.217.163
82.161.217.164
```

I have a code to retrieve the rows in PHP:

```
$sql = "SELECT IP FROM IP";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row["IP"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

So far so good but when I try to select the first occurrence of the row with value "82.161.217.163" I get nothing:

```
//nothing
$sql = "SELECT IP FROM IP WHERE IP='82.161.217.163'";

//nothing
$sql = "SELECT IP FROM IP WHERE 'IP=82.161.217.163'";

//no good
echo $row["IP"][0]. "<br>";

//no good
echo $row["IP"]["82.161.217.163"]. "<br>";
```

I tried many other stuff but nothing seems to give result "82.161.217.163"

Comment: when you say nothing, do you mean "echo 0 results"?  Add your diagnostic stuff.  var_dump $conn, $result, etc.  Make sure you have what you think you have.

Comment: @phpmeh Yes in many cases I get echo "0 results";

Comment: Also, I'm not sure if the syntax is getting confused by the same names.  You may write out your SQLs full just to make sure it knows how to interpret it:
SELECT `IP`.`IP` FROM `IP` WHERE `IP`.`IP` = '82.161.217.163'";

Comment: Each of those gray backgrounds are tick marks.  Apparently that gets taken out.

Comment: Try running your query directly in DB (e.g. from phpmyadmin). If no results will be fetched, see if your values in DB have no trailing spaces or smth.

Comment: @phpmeh I just changed the column name in "num" and test it again, same result (nothing)

Comment: @Maug Lee Thanks but values don't have trailing spaces

Comment: @Youss do you get results when run your query directly in DB?

Comment: @Maug Lee Hi thanks for sticking around, I dont know what you mean by "directly in DB" I see valeus in DB of course. I think the problem is other code which was adding IP adresses on the fly and removing other IP's. This was done also in PHP in the same script. So I took out those codes and created the DB again in a manual way and now everything works. So somehow other coding was messing up stuff. I think the way I was adding and removing the IP's was feeding "bad.." strings or something. Again thanks for your time

Comment: @phpmeh That last comment was also directed to you:)

Comment: Glad you fixed it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the ip address has spaces (or other characters) at the beginning or end.  Try using `like` with wildcards:

```
SELECT IP
FROM IP
WHERE IP LIKE '%82.161.217.163%'
```

Note:  You might get 182.161.217.163, but this is worth a try.

Comment: Thanks for "WHERE IP LIKE" I think this is better than "FROM IP WHERE"